# How to solve random non-linear system of equations?

Tags: java, c

I used matlab, the built-in solve function is amazing.

It takes a set of strings with `x`,`y`,`z` or anything in it, and solve any nonlinear system of equations with almost all possible solutions.

Like:

```
x^2 + y^3 = 2
sin(y) * diff(log (x)) = 3
```

It can solve this and give all solutions.....

How can I do this? I know Newton's Law and Secant, but to give all solutions seem too hard. Is there any lib out there? Java or C++

Comment: Numerical methods, aka guess and check cleverly.

Comment: How can if give "all solutions"? A system of transcendental equations may potentially have infinitely many solutions...

Comment: [Numerical Recipies](http://www.nr.com/) provide a good starting point. You could also check the solvers in the [GSL library](http://www.gnu.org/s/gsl/manual/html_node/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MATLAB itself with C++ using [MATLAB Engine](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f29148.html) or [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/index.html)